# Losing quality in image when sending to back end

Tags: javascript, http, base64, filereader

The user uploads a photo which is then edited and cropped using [Croppie](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/). The edited and cropped version is the one that needs to be saved in the back end.

The current code takes the edited image, saves it in the database though when fetched, it displays the edited image though it has lost colour/not showing colours (displayed below)

Image being sent:

[image]

Image fetched:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
<input id="uploadAvatar" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" />

$('#uploadAvatar).on('change', function(){

     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function (e) { 
          var blob = dataURItoBlob(e.target.result;);
          var fd = new FormData();
          fd.append("file", blob);

          //SERVICE HANDLES THE HTTP REQUEST
          httpUploadAvatarServ('../p3sweb/FileUploadServlet', fd, function (callback) { 
               console.log(callback)
          });
     }  

}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) { 

    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]); 

    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg '});

}
```

**Question**

Why is it that the image is losing quality/colour?

Comment: What plugin are you using to crop the image?

Comment: croppie. I'll add that to the question

Comment: Possibly add the `croppie` tag too. There's only 54 questions in there, but you never know...

Comment: I'm wondering if there's an issue with the conversion of the base64 URI?

Comment: When I use croppie (I am right now actually), I just put the raw base64 in an html input and send it up. Never had any quality issues...

Comment: can you test on pure color image? I guess maybe the rgb order is messed up.

Comment: or do you test if it's OK before send to server?

Comment: @silencedogood I don't suppose you have code that could go to demonstrate? Possibly as answer?

Comment: @appleapple cropped image is fine on client-side before sending

Comment: What appleapple said... could you check with `window.location = URL.createObjectURL(blob);`? Else I would look in the network tab (to eliminate css filters) and on the stored file on the server and then at the file that handles the upload.

Comment: Yeah just did and image is fine :/

Comment: Also in the network tap and on the server?

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott then it's not frontend issue. What's the code on your backend? and how's the image look like at backend?

Comment: and did you test it on pure color image (like a red/blue/green one)? it can simply be your backend using different RGB order.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be in the dataURItoBlob function. Here's how I go about getting the base64 data with croppie before sending it to the server. Tried to abridge my code for simplicity... Hopefully I didn't make it worse:

```
function PlaceLargeImg (input, imgId, zindex) {
    var $imgel = $(imgId);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        // Sets preview image src to the value of file input.
        $imgel.attr('src', e.target.result);

        // Bind croppie
        cropperlg.bind({
            url: $imgel.attr('src')
        });
        // On click method which crops and sets results to html input.
        $('.btn-crop-lg').on('click', () => {
            cropperlg.result({
                type: 'canvas',
                size: {width: 1000, height: 400}
            }).then(function(result) {
                $('#base64lg').val(result); // Resulting cropped img base64 that gets sent to server.
                $('#uploadLg').submit(); 
            });
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

EDIT: If your image looks good in a clint-side preview AFTER parsing through dataUritoBlob, then the issue is on the server. In this case, you'll need to post your server side code.